# What is this long brown bug

Tags: bugs, bug-identification

Seemingly out of nowhere a long insect creature appeared (jumped?) on my PC screen and startled me.
Seems to have 6 legs and antennae. Moves slowly, but apparently has a very strong grip. Its size is about 2.5cm (1")
The bug was found in the capital city of Bulgaria, EU.

An app identified it as a house cricket and then a box bug, but while it does look like that I couldn't match a picture that looks identical.

Looks something between an adult gonocerus acuteangulatus and rhombic leatherbug but it has longer and thinner body. Most likely in the family Coreidae.

What is it?
[image: Long legged insect]

Comment: It is still alive in the glass I am keeping it in. The only greenies I had touched are iceberg and arugula that I was eating so I've thrown a leaf of both in there, hoping that it'll keep it alive for longer. Poor thing is probably starving too.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found it: Nagusta goedelii

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagusta_goedelii):
Nagusta goedelii is a species of assassin bugs in the family Reduviidae.
This species is present in Central and Southern Europe (Austria, Bosnia and Herzegovina, **Bulgaria**...

[image: Nagusta Goedelii]

Recently, I nearly recovered from Indianmeal moth infestation and it is possible that goedelii fed on them.